# In Excel 2010, how can I show a count of occurrences on a specific date within multiple time ranges?

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have three columns of data.  ID, Date(MM/DD/YY), Time(00:00).

I need to create a chart or table that shows the number of occurrences on, say, 12/10/2010 between 00:00 and 00:59, 1:00 and 1:59, etc, for each hour of the day.

I can do countif and get results for the date, but I cannot figure out how to show a summary of the count of occurrences per hour for the 24 hour period.  I have months of data and many times each day.  Example of data set is below.  Any help is greatly

```
ID     Date          Time  
221    12/10/2010    00:01  
223    12/10/2010    00:45  
227    12/10/2010    01:13  
334    12/11/2010    14:45
```

I would like the results to read:

```
Date          Time               Count  
12/10/2010    00:00AM - 00:59AM    2  
12/10/2010    01:00AM - 01:59AM    1  
12/10/2010    02:00AM - 02:59AM    0  
......(continues for every hour of the day)  
12/11/2010    00:00AM - 00:59AM    0  
.........  
12/11/2010    14:00PM - 14:59PM    1
```

And so on.   Sorry for the length but I wanted to be clear.

**EDIT**
Here is a sample spreadsheet.  Very little data, but I couldn't figure out a better way without having a huge file.  Tested in notepad for formatting and worked ok on import as csv.

```
PID,Date,Time  
2888759,12/10/2010,0:10  
2888760,12/10/2010,0:10  
2888761,12/10/2010,0:10  
2888762,12/10/2010,0:11  
2889078,12/10/2010,15:45  
2889079,12/10/2010,15:57  
2889080,12/10/2010,15:57  
2889081,12/10/2010,15:58  
2889082,12/10/2010,16:10  
2889083,12/10/2010,16:11  
2889084,12/10/2010,16:11  
2889085,12/10/2010,16:12  
2889086,12/10/2010,16:12  
2889087,12/10/2010,16:12  
2889088,12/10/2010,16:13  
2891529,12/14/2010,16:21
```

Answer (score 4):

Upload a sample spreadsheet with some entries and someone will do it for you. This is the type of problem that requires some playing around with countifs and breaking apart ranges in different ways.

*Edit*
The solution you're looking for is `=COUNTIFS(B:B,E3,C:C,">="&F3,C:C,"<"&G3)`

Here is the context:
[image: Solution]

In this solution, each row adds up the number of items in the entire data set where the date is equal to your target date in the summary table, where the time is greater than or equal to the start time, and where the time is less than the end time. When all of these conditions are met, the data entry is counted. Excel is pretty smart about adjusting the actual cells checked to just the used range, so you don't need to worry about the fact that is looks at the entire columns B and C.

Comment: Solution added. Thanks Justin.

Comment: Wow.  Never, ever would have figured that out.  Don't even realize what you did now that I can see it.  lol   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create one column where the formula concatenates the date and time and then rounds it to the hour.

Rounding can be done like this

`ROUNDUP( A1*24, 0) / 24`

Then use `CountIf` to get the count

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb239247%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I do have one question about the concat comment.  How are you suggesting I concat the date and time, while also rounding to the hour?   Sorry for the ignorance here, but I've never run into anything like this.

Comment: @Justin you can use something like `ROUNDUP( A1*24, 0) / 24`

Comment: Thanks Raj.  If you don't mind, please see the data I uploaded.  Your skill far outweighs mine.  If you have a moment, can you try that data?